# which file should I run in Git Repositories?

Tags: eclipse, github

I'm using eclipse. I created a git repository and pulled some code from a url. I want to run that code but when I try to run, I get this error:

Select what to run:

Ant Build

Ant Build...

Is the code in git repository not executable? 
How can I run this project? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "run its main file"?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I just want to run the project. So I tried to run the file which has main method in it.

Answer (score 2):

A git repo doesn't know about the nature of the text files it stores: it just make sure they are replicated exactly the same.

Once clone, you need to check haw the project work, independently of Git.
In this case, see "[Eclipse: Running Ant buildfiles](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-84_run_ant.htm)", or use the [Ant view in Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-85a_ant_view.htm).
You can [make one of the ant target run automatically too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5664736/6309).

If this isn't an ant project, see:

- "[what is this ANT build?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573910/6309)".
- make sure your java project as a builder (if not, by default, Eclipse proposes ant), as in "[Eclipse won't compile/run java file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23065520/6309)"

Comment: Should I coppy the files in git repo to another Java Project to run? Because the files have the empty J as in "Eclipse won't compile/run java file". When I try to import the files from git repo to a new project I get this error: Cannot create file because existing file of wrong type exists.

Comment: @bug you can try to create a new java project and compare the two, to spot what is missing in the one from the git repo.